# How to avoid incurring in lifetime errors while filter with an `async` predicate?

Tags: rust, async-await

Using an `async` predicate to filter a list of values makes Rust complain about lifetimes. Even if the collection is `await`ed, which means the predicate will not outlive the filtered value, Rust remains skeptical.

Full repro below with [playground here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e24aa4fc46563094402954e41630fa77). Note that it filters on a non-copy struct we'd rather pass by reference, rather than a simple value we could just copy and forget without incurring in overhead.

```rust
use futures::stream::iter;
use futures::StreamExt;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    bar: usize
}

impl Foo {
    fn new(bar: usize) -> Self {
        Self {
            bar
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let arr = vec![
      Foo::new(0),
      Foo::new(1),
      Foo::new(2)
    ];
    
    let filtered = iter(arr)
      .filter(|f| async {compute_baz(f).await > 0})
      .collect::<Vec<_>>()
      .await; 

    // should print Foo{bar:1} and Foo{bar:2}
    println!("{:?}", filtered) 
}

async fn compute_baz(foo: &Foo) -> usize {
    // ...do lengthy task...
    
    foo.bar
}
```

---

#### Update

As @Ceasar pointed out below, the async functions are not run in parallel, can that be done?

I'm trying to do something like:

```rust
let filter_mask = join_all(items.map(predicate)); 
let filtered = items.filter(|i| filter_mask[i]).collect::<Vec<_>>();
```

without the clutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround is to avoid the closure:

```rust
let mut filtered = vec![];
for f in arr.iter() {
    if compute_baz(f).await > 0 {
        filtered.push(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't this filters sequentially? I'm trying to run the `.await` in parallel,
but maybe the `stream` translates to your version now that I think of it.

I was thinking of doing something like `let filter_mask = join_all(items.map(predicate); let filtered = items.filter(|i| filter_mask[i].collect()` w/out the clutter

Comment: I assumed so but didn't really think about it. Just to make sure: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=48e2be110c40afa74f9effaeac488b8a). If you want this to be parallel, you'd need `buffer_unordered`, I think. But then you're back to your lifetime problems.

Comment: @doplumi You should probably edit your question to include that requirement so someone can answer it properly. Because I've [gone astray](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fe9882561a7d15d99752f013087c796c)…

Comment: looking at it now, didn't know about `buffer_unordered`